# JUnit test with format (String, String, Enum)

Tags: java, junit, enums

My professor requires that the JUnit Test be in this format

```
company = new Company("New Source");
    company.addEmployee("John", "Smith","Manufacturing");
    company.addEmployee("Bob", "Brown", "Manufacturing");
    company.addEmployee("Harold", "Jones", "Sales");
    company.addEmployee("Betty","Boop", "Design");
```

but the problem is the method is in this format

```
public String addEmployee(String fName, String lName, Position p)
```

and it has to be the Position is an enumerated method. So how can I make the JUnit test run properly. And btw this is how my enum class looks so it should be working.

```
//in Position.java
public enum Position {
DESIGN("Design"),
MANUFACTURING("Manufacturing"),
SALES("Sales");

private final String positionName;


private Position(String positionName) {
    this.positionName= positionName;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return positionName;
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "enumerated method"?  Is `Position` an enum?

Comment: yes position is an enum

Comment: I just edited the question so you can also see the enum aswell

Comment: Okay...so then it seems now that you're passing in a `String` instead of a `Position`.  Try it with `Position.MANUFACTURING`, for example.

Comment: so change the JUnit test?

Comment: Change your method call.  You're not calling it with the appropriate types.  Something along the lines of "String, String, String cannot be applied to String, String, Position".

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to say. So where should I change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't change the method signature, you have two options: pass the enumerated value explicitly, or use the valueOf method and use the strings that correspond to the enum's values.

So rather than

```
company = new Company("New Source");
company.addEmployee("John", "Smith","Manufacturing");
```

Use either

```
company = new Company("New Source");
company.addEmployee("John", "Smith", Position.MANUFACTURING);
```

or

```
company = new Company("New Source");
company.addEmployee("John", "Smith", Position.valueOf("Manufacturing"));
```

Comment: No problem.  Java enums are pretty powerful compared to other languages.  Once you're done with the assignment, try working through the examples in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).